# Web scraped data comes back blank

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a specific table from a website and get a specific piece of data within that table. I'm pretty sure the code I'm using should work but it returns nothing but []. That's just for finding the row of data, I haven't even gotten to the specific piece of data I want yet.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
   
url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/cade-cunningham-1.html'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
advanced = soup.findAll('tr', id = 'players_advanced.2021')
advanced
```

If you go to the website, the table I want to web scrape is the 'Advanced' stats table and pull the USG% from it. I only want the USG data for the 2021 season.

Also, when I just enter 'soup' I see what I want to get is in there, but when I say `soup.findAll('th')` it only returns the headers for the first table  on the website even though there are many. I don't know why that is.

Comment: "Even though there are many..." Can you find **those** when you `print(soup)`? If not, then the tables are loaded after the page is rendered and `requests` is the wrong tool to get the website data

Comment: @EvanWright, convention is when there is an acceptable solution that you accept it. You have quite a few posts in the last few days and have not accepted a single solution. Please go back and accept the solutions that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is inside the page in the form of HTML comment (`<!-- -->`). To parse it, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/cade-cunningham-1.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.find("h2", text="Advanced").find_next(
    text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment)
)
data = BeautifulSoup(str(data), "html.parser")

for tr in data.select("tbody tr"):
    row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    usgs = row[18]
    print(usgs)
```

Prints:

```
29.1
```

Comment: The commented sections may well hold outdated data - OP should probably use a JavaScript-capable package like `selenium` or similar to process the page before scraping.

Comment: @Grismar, as far as I'm aware, it's not outdated on reference.com sites. Can you give an example of where the data is outdated?